# NSUserDefaults in SWIFT - Intro ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have a small problem in my app, the thing is that I have an intro screen - It's a screen that is supposed to greet people once and never show that screen again. The problem is that I can't seem to get the app to "remember" that it has opened once. I made a button in the bottom, which I thought I could use as a save button but it did not work properly. The Intro screen was always the initial viewcontroller.

So my question is, is there a way to use NSUserDefaults in SWIFT on a button, so that when the user clicks on it once. The introscreen will not open again. The user will just be directed to the next viewcontroller. Which in my case is a tableview.

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func NextViewcontroller(sender: AnyObject)
{
    let startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as ContentViewController
    let viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)

    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)


}

func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> ContentViewController
{
    if ((self.pageTitles.count == 0) || (index >= self.pageTitles.count)) {
        return ContentViewController()
    }

    let vc: ContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ContentViewController") as! ContentViewController

    vc.imageFile = self.pageImages[index] as! String
    vc.titleText = self.pageTitles[index] as! String
    vc.pageIndex = index

    return vc

}



// MARK: - Page View Controller Data Source

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
{

    let vc = viewController as! ContentViewController
    var index = vc.pageIndex as Int


    if (index == 0 || index == NSNotFound)
    {
        return nil

    }

    index--
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)

}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let vc = viewController as! ContentViewController
    var index = vc.pageIndex as Int

    if (index == NSNotFound)
    {
        return nil
    }

    index++

    if (index == self.pageTitles.count)
    {
        return nil
    }

    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)

}

func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int
{
    return self.pageTitles.count
}

func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int
{
    return 0
}
}
```

Comment: What's the connection between this code and the question?  (I don't see any NSUserDefaults logic at all.)

Comment: The connection is that, I have all this code - But for some strange reason I could not get NSUserDefaults to work.

Comment: but on your question `NSUserDefaults` is mentioned in anywhere on your code

Comment: It certainly doesn't work if you don't use it.  More to the point, it's hard for people to debug something you once wrote and then deleted.

Comment: That is because, I could not get it to work, I was looking for a helping solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented same kind of thing in my app

```
  if let IsTermsVisible = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(PrefTermsAndCondition) as? Bool {
        print ("BreakIsTermsVisible ")
        if IsTermsVisible == true {
            tncView.hidden = true
        }
        else {
            tncView.hidden = false
        }
    }
    else {
        tncView.hidden = false
        print ("false IsTermsVisible ")
    }
```

I have added one OK button in a view once user press ok it will never show in app.

```
@IBAction func tncBtnClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: PrefTermsAndCondition)
    tncView.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: So I tried using your method, but it kept saying that 

"Type "WelcomeScreen" has no member 'hidden'" 

I kept saying that for all three of them, why is that?

Comment: @SaranganRajenthram I have used UIView which is having hidden functionality. I have implemented as per my requirement. you have to write logic according to your requirement.